# О возвратности и переходности причастий

Tags: грамматика, причастия

1. На одном **[из форумов](https://otvet.mail.ru/question/236749055)**  обсуждался вопрос о таких грамматических признаках причастий,  как **переходность и возвратность.** Одни участники считали, что причастия имеют **оба признака**,  другие исключали **переходность или возвратность.**

А как бы **вы ответили** на этот вопрос?

2. Вот задача. Рассмотрим **пять разных причастий:**

(1) видимый, (2) оставшийся, (3) сочиняющий, (4) написанный, (5) строящийся.

**Сколько** причастий возвратных и сколько переходных? Как можно быстро сделать вывод по **внешнему** виду причастий?  (Это если они **вообще бывают** возвратными и переходными.)

**P. S.** Вопрос кажется вам очень **простым и неинтересным?** Да, это школьная программа, и знать решение нужно обязательно. Но есть в этой теме **деталь**, которую вы, возможно, упускаете из вида. Не зря же давались такие разные ответы.

Comment: Редкой глупости вопрос. Я думаю у 2 есть признак что оно состоит из 1+1, а вы как считаете, имеет ли оно такой признак?

Comment: Редкой неумности комментарий.  Минус поставили – и до свидания. Обсуждайте тему сами с собой.

Comment: Вот сюда еще напишите, про признаки.  У меня по таким темам ничего своего-то нет и быть не может,  собственных терминов не изобретаю. только чужое пересказываю. Вот если про запятые будет вопрос, тогда обращайтесь.   https://russkiiyazyk.ru/chasti-rechi/glagol/prichastie/morfologicheskie-priznaki-2.html

Answer (score 1):

**РЕШЕНИЕ ЗАДАЧИ**

Рассмотрим пять **разных причастий**: *(1) видимый, (2) оставшийся, (3) сочиняющий, (4) написанный, (5) строящийся.*

1. Возвратность определяем по частице ***СЯ***, как и у глаголов: ***оставшийся*** и ***строящийся.***
2. Переходность указывается только для **ДЕЙСТВИТЕЛЬНЫХ** причастий: ***сочиняющий***. Причастие ***строящийся*** — непереходное, так как имеет частицу ***СЯ*** (показатель возвратности).

**Пояснение**

1. **СТРАДАТЕЛЬНЫЕ** причастия находятся **вне переходности** (не являются ни переходными, ни непереходными), хотя они образуются от **переходных** глаголов.
2. **Переходные** причастия управляют существительным (местоимением) в форме винительного падежа без предлога: **сочиняющий (что?) стихи.**
3. **Сравнить** (для страдательного причастия):  **нельзя сказать**: *написанный (что?),* хотя *написать (что?) роман.* Поэтому для страдательных причастий переходность **не определяют**.
4. Отметим также, что для причастий указывается **залог** как **постоянный** признак, в отличие **от глаголов**.

Для **глагола** залог является **непостоянным** признаком и при разборе не называется. Действительный или страдательный залог определяется для **переходных** глаголов и зависит от того, **что** именно является в предложении **подлежащим** (объект действия или субъект действия).

Comment: Приведите пример глаголов, которые меняют залог в двух разных предложениях

Comment: Вот сюда напишите, материал из этой статьи https://www.kp.ru/edu/shkola/zalog-glagola-v-russkom-yazyke/   Все вам объяснят и примеры приведут. Может быть)

Answer (score 0):

Это комментарий к статье: kp.ru/edu/shkola/zalog-glagola-v-russkom-yazyke
Материалы статьи посвящены странному стилю речи, который «кому-то может показаться более деловым и впечатляющим» за счет замысловатого жонглирования подчиненностью отглагольных словоформ.
Авторы статьи прекрасно сознают искусственность такого стиля, что следует из заключительных фраз:   «тексты, изобилующие страдательным залогом, часто ассоциируются с»...канцелярско-бюрократическим стилем речи, проникающим в среду более широкого употребления, деформируя и разговорный и литературный стили, что воспринимается некоторыми носителями языка и, прежде всего, литературной общественностью как «порча языка», а потому «уместнее использовать понятный и простой действительный залог», обеспечивающий лаконичность формулировок и точность передачи мысли.

Comment: Спасибо за информацию, но залог не тема моего вопроса. В ответе же  я указываю залог в качестве дополнения при сравнении морфол. признаков глагола и причастия.  Общая тема обозначена в вопросе https://otvet.mail.ru/question/236749055

Comment: Ни один из трех ответов не является точным и правильным. Как бы ответили на заданный там вопрос?